# Need assistance with Kohana 3 and catch all route turning into a 404 error

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Based on [this documentation](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=routing:creating_a_custom_404_page), I've implemented a *catch all* route which routes to an error page.

Here is the last route in my `bootstrap.php`

```
Route::set('default', '<path>', array('path' => '.+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'errors',
        'action'     => '404',
    ));
```

However I keep getting this exception thrown when I try and go to a non existent page

> Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Required route
>   parameter not passed: path

If I make the `<path>` segment optional (i.e. wrap it in parenthesis) then it just seems to load the `home` route, which is...

```
Route::set('home', '')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

The home route is defined first.

I execute my main request like so

```
$request = Request::instance();


try {

    // Attempt to execute the response
    $request->execute();

} catch (Exception $e) {


   if (Kohana::$environment === Kohana::DEVELOPMENT) throw $e;

    // Log the error
    Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR, Kohana::exception_text($e));

    // Create a 404 response
    $request->status = 404;
    $request->response = Request::factory(Route::get('default')->uri())->execute();

}

$request->send_headers();
echo $request->response;
```

This means that the 404 header is sent to the browser, but I assumed by sending the request to the capture all route then it should show the 404 error set up in my errors controller.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Errors extends Controller_Base {

    public function before() {
        parent::before();
    }

    public function action_404() {


        $this->bodyClass[] = '404';

        $this->internalView = View::factory('internal/not_found');

        $longTitle = 'Page Not Found';

        $this->titlePrefix = $longTitle;


    }
}
```

Why won't it show my 404 error page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my projects I never specified any specific separated route for 404. I just catch exceptions thrown by routing, when no appropriate route was found.

Here is how I am handling all kind of exceptions that I've discovered in Kohana. I hope it will help you.

```
try
{
    try
    {
        $request = Request::instance();
        $request->execute();
    }
    catch (ReflectionException $e)
    {
        Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR_404, Kohana::exception_text($e));

        if (!IN_PRODUCTION)
        {
        throw $e;
        }

        $request->response = Request::factory('err/404')->execute();
    }
    catch (Exception404 $e)
    {
        Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR_404, Kohana::exception_text($e));

        if (!IN_PRODUCTION)
        {
        throw $e;
        }

        $request->response = Request::factory('err/404')->execute();
    }
    catch (Kohana_Request_Exception $e)
    {
        Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR_404, Kohana::exception_text($e));

        if (!IN_PRODUCTION)
        {
        throw $e;
        }

        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.Kohana::$charset, TRUE, 404);
        echo Request::factory('err/404')->send_headers()->execute()->response;
        exit;
    }
    catch (exception $e)
    {
        Kohana::$log->add(Kohana::ERROR, Kohana::exception_text($e));

        if (!IN_PRODUCTION)
        {
        throw $e;
        }

        $request->status = 500;
        $request->response = Request::factory('err/500')->execute();
    }
}
catch (exception $e)
{
        if (!IN_PRODUCTION)
        {
            throw $e;
        }
        echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
        here is the message that everything is veeeery bad
        </body>
        </html>';
        exit;
}
```

Exception404:

```
class Kohana_Exception404 extends Kohana_Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = 'error 404', array $variables = NULL, $code = 0)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $variables, $code);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you make Exception404 or is that defined by Kohana? Thanks for your answer too :)

Comment: Thanks heaps! This is interesting and helpful so I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured this one out.

This line...

```
$request->response = Request::factory(Route::get('default')->uri())->execute();
```

Was setting the response to the result of `Route::get('default')->uri()`. Looking at it further, I realised it will return an empty string, which will match the `home` route above. I feel silly....