# Catching Kohana_Request_Exception in Kohana v3 during execution -- unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, kohana

As detailed here: [Need assistance with Kohana 3 and catch all route turning into a 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862272/need-assistance-with-kohana-3-and-catch-all-route-turning-into-a-404-error) as the accepted answer to the question, I'm attempting to catch errors thrown by Kohana to display pretty error pages and send correct HTTP codes.

Here's a simplified version to demonstrate the problem:

```
try {
    // Instantiate your Request object
    $request = Request::instance();
    // The give it a try, to see if its a valid request
    $request->execute();
}
catch (Kohana_Request_Exception $e) {
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.Kohana::$charset, TRUE, 404);
    echo Request::factory('err/404')->send_headers()->execute()->response;
    exit;
}
echo $request->send_headers()->response;
```

So I navigate to a non-existent URL such as http://example.local/moo/ and I get the following response

```
Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: moo
```

Here is what's happening-- The request is being tried, failing with a Kohana_Request_Exception, **it's being caught** BUT when I try to build a new request object, `Request::factory('err/404')` THAT request throws the error from my first request....!? wtf??

I've fiddled with it for a good hour and am as puzzled as when I started.  Shouldn't the new request from the factory have no knowledge of the old request?? Why is this code malfunctioning when I essentially copied it from the d00d's answer?

```
// Release version and codename
const VERSION  = '3.0.7';
const CODENAME = 'hattrick';
```

Someone point me in the right direction.. thx guys.

Comment: Do not call `header()` directly. It will just be overwritten by `Request::send_headers().` anyways. Use `Request->headers[]` and `Request->status` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Thanks guys but I got it figured.. I shoulda looked at the stack trace a little closer, the error page's template controller's `before()` method was throwing a new error as it was attempting to check authentication using `Request::instance()`I changed it to `Request::current()` and it's all shiny.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because within `Request::factory('err/404')`, the `err/404` part is a URL that is trying to be matched by your routes as well. Will it ever match, i.e. do you have a route with something like this...

```
Route::set('errors', 'err/<action>', array('action' => '404|500')) {}
```

You should also be sending a 404 via...

```
$request->status = 404;
```